# How can I access to linux file system read/write speed in c program?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, metrics

I need to access to linux kernel metrics, one of them is the file system read and write speed.

I know there are commands such as 'dd', 'hdparm' and 'iotop' that give information about the file system's data transfer speed, but I don't know how can I read this information in my C program and then, for example, I print the speed in console.

If there is a file which it has speed information it can be read file in C program and access to speed.
How can this be done? 
Thank you. [image]

---

I read [iostats.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt) documentation.The file ***/proc/diskstats*** has 11 parameter for each row. According to iostats.txt, for each row 3rd parameter is total number of reading sectors and 4th parameter is the total number of reading time in milliseconds. 
If [every sector is 4096 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector), so the reading speed formula must be:
[speed = (($3) * 4096 )/ $4](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?speed%20%3D%20%28%28%243%29%20*%204096%20%29/%20%244%20*%201000%20MB%20per%20Seconds%20%28MB/Sec%29)      ($x means parameter x)

[image]

but when I calculated reading speed of my flash memory, it was 0.2 MB/sec although it must be about 7 Mb/sec according to the command  ***iostat -k 2***  or gnu disk utility (graphical app).
How can I evaluate speed from these parameters, what is correct formula for evaluating speed in MB/Sec ?

Comment: Define “system's data transfer speed.” The figure you show in the image (please don't post text as an image) is the transfer speed of one file transfer, not of the system (whatever that is).

Comment: I want to get file system reading speed like the command: 
[  _iostat -k 2_  ]  
in my C program

Comment: Why don't you say that in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The file `/proc/diskstats` contains statistics about disk performance. Documentation about how to interpret its contents can be found in the kernel tree in file [`Documentation/iostats.txt`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/iostats.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.4-rc7).